# Dump file handle number in perl

Tags: perl

Can we dump value of file handle number in perl.

For example when I write `function(STDOUT)` it should gives o/p `1`.

I tried

```
my $fh = \*STDOUT;
print Dumper $fh
```

it prints `$VAR1 = \*::STDOUT`

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fileno()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html):

```
print fileno($fh);
```